# Allow user to run programs as root without password. Would it be the correct solution to my problem?

Tags: wine, sudo, root, cron, privileges

I have a server which I need to be running certain programs permanently; I'm having problems with two of them and I'm not sure if the solution I've found would be the correct one, so I ask for opinion to users with more experience on this issues.

- On one hand I have a cron-task-launched script which connects to an FTP to update the IP of the server so, in case the IP (it's a dynamic one) changes, I can check the FTP to get the current IP so I can connect to the server.
- On the other hand, I have a wine-launched program which also needs to connect to another FTP account and execute from time to time other commands which need root privileges.

What's my problem?

If I login and launch these processes, they run perfectly for hours, even if I let the session "go to the block-password-asking-screen", I guess it's because they execute the processes which need root password quite often (maybe every 2-10 minutes), but if they stop executing those processes, if for example, they don't need to connect to the FTP for 5 or 10 hours, after that time they can't do it until I login again, and in that exact moment they are able again to connect to the FTP.

So, after reading quite information about it, I guess the solution would be to edit /etc/sudoers and add a line similar to this one:

```
user_X ALL=NOPASSWD:/home/user_X/script.sh
```

So this user (the processes running on it's session) be able to access FTP permanently. In fact, the wine-launched process, won't be able to connect again even if I login, so I guess wine needs it's own permission, so maybe I should something different instead of that?

I'm not sure about it to be the right solution. Could anyone please confirm me it is?

Thanks a lot in advance.

EDIT:

command used to edit cron tasks:

```
sudo crontab -u root -e
```

line I've added to (try to) make it work:

```
*/30 * * * * /home/user_X/check_public_IP.sh > /home/user_X/Desktop/cron_res.txt
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this is really not clear. Could you show us the relevant cron lines? What user's crontab is launching them? Who needs root password? Please [edit] your question and include the actual commands being run and specify where/why the root password is required.

Comment: Sure. I'm editing my post to add that information.

Comment: Thanks for the edit but I still don't know why the root password is needed. What is this wine program? Why does it need root? How can a wine program even need the root password? Are you connecting to the FTP as root? Is that the password you mean? Who is userX? You seem to be running he cron as root.

Comment: absolutely do NOT allow a script at a non full hierarchy root folder (the folder and parents all must be root writable only) to be run with root privileges! users may not be able to edit the script owned by root, but they can delete and recreate it (wont be owned by root tho) and will be the same path/filename!